# Category pages redirecting to tab on Posts page grid

Tags: categories, redirect, seo

I have a Posts page (https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/) which has a tab/button for each Category. I would like my Category pages to open this tab instead of loading the default Category page. Is there a way to do this so that the Category title and meta description (via Yoast) which I will set will show in Google, but the tab of the Posts page load instead of just the Category page?

I have Categories in two hierarchies; single level ones, and ones which are a sub-category below the main Category of "Country".

Examples:

https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/category/education/
this should load https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/?tx_category=education

https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/category/country/japan/
this should load https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/locations/?tx_category=japan

Would a simple 301 or 302 redirect cause the Google entry title/meta/url to show the redirected page info and pass rank to the Posts/Locations page? I have tried to read around the subject and not sure.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have done this via category.php

`/* Redirect Category to Post Grid tab */
<?php
$cat = get_queried_object();
wp_redirect( site_url('/locations/').'?tx_category='.$cat->slug );
exit();`